# A question about the real projective space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space

I came across the definition of the $n$-dimensional real projective space $\Bbb RP^n$ in the lecture notes given by our instructor. The definition is as follows $:$

Let us take the $n$-sphere $\Bbb S^n$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ and let it be acted by $C_2 = \{1,\tau\},$ the cyclic group of order $2$ by $$\tau \cdot x = -x,\ x \in \Bbb S^n.$$ Then $\Bbb R P^n : = \Bbb S^n/C_2,$ the space where we identify antipodal points (diametrically opposite points) of $\Bbb S^n.$ So $\Bbb R P^n$ is essentially lines in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ passing through the origin.

This is where I get stuck. How do I think of the space $\Bbb S^n$ with the antipodal points being identified as being equivalent to the space of all lines in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ passing through the origin? Can anybody give me some geometric intuition of visualizing that space? Any help in this regard will be highly solicited.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is a bijection between the set of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ lines passing through the origin and $\Bbb R P^n$:

A line passing through the origin intersects $\mathbb S^n$ at exactly two antipodal points, i.e. one point of $\Bbb R P^n$. And given a point in $\Bbb R P^n$, you can get two antipodal points of $\mathbb S^n$ which define a single line passing through the origin.

This is what is meant with the word *identification*.

Comment: Does this bijection give us a homeomorphism? Because we know that two topological spaces are equivalent or same if they are homeomorphic.

Comment: There is indeed a topology defined on $\math R P^n$: the topology of the [quotient space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)). However, to answer your question, you should ask yourself what topology you should endow the set a lines passing through the origin.

Comment: If I endow a topology on the space of all lines $S$ (say) passing through  the origin in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ in such a way that a subset of $S$ is open if and only if it's image under the bijective correspondence (between $S$ and $\Bbb R P^n$) is open. Then the said bijection gives rise to a homeomorphism of the underlying spaces. Am I right?

Comment: @Phibetakappa Yes, that is correct by the very definition of continuity.

Answer (score 1):

For each line $L \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ through the origin, the intersection $L \cap \mathbb S^n$ is an antipodal pair of points.

Conversely, for each antipodal pair of points $\{x,-x\} \subset \mathbb S^n$, the line in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ that passes through the two points $x$ and $-x$ also passes through the origin.

Therefore, we obtain a bijection between the set of lines in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ that pass through the origin and the set of antipodal pairs of points in $\mathbb S^n$. The "equivalence" referred to in your post is simply a reference to this bijection.

Comment: Does this bijection give us a homeomorphism? Because we know that two topological spaces are equivalent or same if they are homeomorphic.

Comment: From the information in your post, no topology has been assigned to the "space" of lines in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ through the origin, and so asking whether they are homeomorphic makes no sense. There are some approaches to this issue, but pursuit of those is probably best left to another question.

Comment: If I endow a topology on the space of all lines $S$ (say) passing through  the origin in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ in such a way that a subset of $S$ is open if and only if it's image under the bijective correspondence (between $S$ and $\Bbb R P^n$) is open. Then the said bijection gives rise to a homeomorphism of the underlying spaces. Am I right?